# Problem Solving an Inverse Function

Tags: calculus

I need help with this maths problem please.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

You need 50 kg of two commodities costing €1.25 and €1.60 per kg. The total cost (y) of the purchases is given by the formula
                                   y = 1.25x + 1.60(50 - x)
where x is the number of kg of the less expensive commodity. 
(I) Find the inverse function of the cost function. What does each variable represent
    in the inverse function?
(ii) What is the domain of the inverse function? Validate or explain your answer using 
     the context of the problem.
(iii) Determine the number of kilograms of the less expensive commodity purchased if the
      total cost is €73.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Write the equation y = 1.25 x + 1.60 (50 - x) in the form x = ... using basic manipulations of equations.  Using the distibutive property you get 
$$
y = -0.35 x + 80
$$

Now put this equation into the form x = ... instead of y = ...

Comment: I get y = (-100x/35 + 8000/35) or y = 2.85714(80 - x)

Comment: Where do I go from here?

Comment: Any more suggestions please